# Jspdf unable to show specific combination of hindi letters specifically the letter क्षा

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, hindi

As title says, I am using jspdf for a project and I use it to show hindi characters in a pdf but letters like क्षा appears as क and ष. Strange thing is that when its copied from the pdf and pasted on a textfield here, the character appears correctly.  So far I have used devanagari and noto sans font provided by google but neither has helped. What to do next?